# Variation in decidability of diophantine equations with field extension

Tags: nt.number-theory, computability-theory, diophantine-equations, decidability

Let $O_k$ be the ring of integers in a subfield $k$ of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Let's call an equation $p(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0$ where $p$ is a polynomial in $n$-variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$ with coefficients in $O_k$, a *$k$-diophantine equation*.

When $k$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, the problem of decidability of existence of an $O_k$-solution to a general $k$-diophantine equation has been settled in negative by the famous MRDP solution to Hilbert's 10th problem. In fact the negative result has been extended to all abelian extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ by Shapiro and Shlapentokh.

On the other hand, over the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, solutions to any polynomial equation with coefficients in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ clearly exist.

I am curious about the variation in decidability as we go from abelian extensions to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

I am wondering if there is a precise sense (some sort of "degree of decidability", e.g., a weighted fraction of diophantine equations for which there is a decision algorithm, for a naïve measure) in which the problem becomes "more and more decidable" as the "complexity" of $k$ goes up, as measured by the "complexity" of associated Galois group in some sense, or by some other criteria.

Is there a discussion of this issue somewhere?